# A way to use ng-bind-html with other attribute

Tags: angularjs, css, ngsanitize

There is anything in angularJs which can intercept html code besides than ng-bind-html?
In my code I found a problem when using ng-bind-html because in my css page I define a style using data-title attribute.
So now I need data-title attribute because I'm using it into my css and also I need the ng-bind-html to intercept the html code but the problem is that data-title and ng-bind-html don't work together in my example.

```
<p data-title="{{user.name}}" ></p>
<p ng-bind-html="user.name"></p>

.card.opened  p:after{
content:attr(data-title);
transform: rotateY( 180deg );
display: block;
}
```

UPDATE:

To explain more what I'm trying to do:
I have a reverse card and when I click on the card it should return and show the content (data-title) with a formatted text, So to manage the return of the card I'm using the css above, (with data-title) and to intercept the html code I'm using ng-bind-html.

Comment: What does `ng-bind-html` have to do with the code shown? Question is not properly detailed

Comment: could you explain the problem has happened and what do you expect?

Comment: So what's wrong with `<p data-title="{{user.name}}" ng-bind-html="user.name"></p>`

Comment: @charlietfl  can you please check the update

Comment: @RicardoPontual can you please check the update

Comment: Create a plunker demo that reproduces problem. Your update doesn't make it clear what issue is. *"I define a style using data-title attribute"* ... that's not shown in code. Also go through [ask]

Comment: Are you using the `$sce.trustAsHtml` service? There are other ways to bypass SCE but it is not wise to do so.